# Facebook renamed callback parameters if application is rejected

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I have a `facebook login` button on my website and I include data in it.
So my `callback url` looks like `http://my.domain/callback/facebook/?my_param=my_data`.

Once the user goes on the application permissions page and either accept or reject my app, it would always come back as

> `http://my.domain/callback/facebook/?code=code&my_param=my_data` #accepted

or

> `http://my.domain/callback/facebook/?error=error_data&my_param=my_data` #rejected

And I just noticed today that Facebook now renamed my `my_param` to `0` when the application is rejected. (i.e. `http://my.domain/callback/facebook/?error=error_data&0=my_data`)

I did not find anything in the `developers.facebook.com` documentation.

- Does someone know why it changed?
- What are the rules applied to rename the parameters?
- Is there any documentation about this change?

Comment: Read a similar problem description somewhere a few days ago … I’d call this a bug, so I’d suggest you check the bug tracker if there’s already a bug filed for this, and if not create one.

Comment: This is a known issue, please see related bug here and subscribe to the bug for updates - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292294647538649

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug has been fixed by facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292294647538649